# Excel CF: Matching (2) columns of text that begin the same, end different

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

Looking for assistance with the following:
A & B are a list of companies. The goal is to highlight in B companies that match A

Conditional Formatting: `=MATCH(LEFT(A2,8)&"*", $B$2:$B$24,0)`

Issue is it is matching incorrect items and is missing others.

[image: IMG:]

All of the companies begin with the same text, but may end differently.

I've tried about a hundred combinations of formulas and can't seem to crack it. Am I getting close? Thank you in advance for reviewing!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Using the latest 365 version

Comment: Got it to work - thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your version of Excel supports dynamic arrays, you can use this formula (adjust the ranges appropriately):

```
=OR(LEFT(B2,LEN(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$5)))=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$5))
```

Step by step, you get the transposed array of column A:

[image]

Then take the left-most N characters of the value in column B, where N is defined by the length of each array item:

[image]

Now compare each array item with another copy of the transposed values from column A. If they match, it will be TRUE, otherwise it will be FALSE:

[image]

Finally, wrap the whole thing with OR to say "if there are any matches, then return TRUE".

I've put the formula and results in column C to visualize the function's result, but you can just use the full OR function above in your conditional format rule, as I have done as well.

[image]

EDIT:

Now that I re-read it, it will of course work without the TRANSPOSE calls, so you can use this just as well:

```
=OR(LEFT($B2,LEN($A$2:$A$5))=$A$2:$A$5)
```

Comment: Flex - thank you for your post - trying this one out!

Answer (score 0):

You may try out this:

1. List one is in Column A, List 2 is in Column B, With headings in 1 st row.
2. In C1 give the heading Match
3. In C2 enter the formula:  `=IFERROR ( FIND (B2, $A$2:$A$51),  0  )`

   I have presumed 50 Rows, say. If B2 is found in List 1 it will return 1, else 0.
4. Copy C2 down the rows.
5. Now, select the area `B2:C51`. See that B2 is highlighted.
6. Go to Conditional Formatting on Home Tab.
7. Select the Option ---> " Manage the rule "
8. In text box which checks the condition enter the formula given below in Step 9
9. `=$C2=1` and Select the colour of your choice.
10. See that the Companies Found in List 1 are highlighted.

Comment: Harshad and Reddy - thank you for post and edits - still trying out these options - thank you for assistance!

Comment: Got it to work, thank you all for the help!